# TW Bootstrap: How to overflow columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to have a row where columns are going to be horizontally scrollable:

[image: scrollable columns in a single row in twitter bootstrap]

As you can see the row is the outer block (with padding). Inside of it, there are columns where each has some `span*` class such as `span3`. And since all of the columns do not fit in the row, the scrollbar is on the bottom.

Here is what I tried doing (with inline css) and so far no luck.

```
<div class="row">

<!-- the parent element which will have scrollbar -->
<div class="span12" style="white-space: nowrap; overflow-x: auto;">

<div class="row">

<div class="span3" style="display: inline-block;">content here</div>
<div class="span3" style="display: inline-block;">content here</div>
<div class="span3" style="display: inline-block;">content here</div>
...

<div>

</div>

</div>
```

But then the columns just wrap once they can't fit into the row. How can I do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Updated**

I guess you just missed the `float: none;` : `float` forces `display: block;`.

[Live demo (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/D3LuT/)

```html
<div class="myClass">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span5"></div>
        <div class="span5"></div>
        <div class="span5"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
div.myClass {
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
div.myClass [class*="col"], /* TWBS v3 */
div.myClass [class*="span"] {  /* TWBS v2 */
    display: inline-block;
    float: none; /* Very important */
}
```

Anyway this is not because you can do it that you should. There are things like [carousels](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel) that can achieve this kind of effects.

IMHO **a web page is originally meant to be horizontally scrolled** whereas JavaScript can do anything.

Comment: Ill give it a try. Why `pre` tag?

Comment: thanx. It works perfectly!. I made a fiddle with the solution. In there if everything fits, then no scollbars appear, otherwise scollbars appears. I was missing `float: none` which you pointed out. http://jsfiddle.net/miki725/9Ndjw/

Comment: @Sherbrow  is it possible to have the  horizontal scroll to respond to user swipe gestures rather than controlling the scroll bar, also I wouldn't want the scroll bar to be visible

Comment: I was trying to solve the same problem and this worked like a charm...thanks.

Comment: works great! updated with latest bootstrap 3 (3.3.5 at the time of this writing): http://jsfiddle.net/s3logic/ou9er1n7/

Comment: I know this is an old answer but I can't help wondering, why should a page be scrolled horizontally? If you write a basic html page with no html or css it would be scrolled vertically.

Answer (score 3):

I took it a bit further. Scrollable horizontal columns!

```
   div.h-scrollable {
overflow-x: auto;
white-space: nowrap; 
}



 div.h-scrollable [class*="col"] {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    white-space: normal;
    vertical-align: top;
  }

    <div class="h-scrollable container-fluid ">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <label>9:00am</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <label>Blah blah blah blah blah blahBlah blah blah blah blah blahBlah blah blah blah blah blahBlah blah blah blah blah blahBlah blah blah blah blah blahBlah blah blah blah blah blahBlah blah blah blah blah blahBlah blah blah blah blah blah</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <label>Blah blah blah blah blah blah</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <label>BBlah blah blah blah blah blahBlah blah blah blah blah blahBlah blah blah blah blah blahBlah blah blah blah blah blahBlah blah blah blah blah blahBlah blah blah blah blah blahBlah blah blah blah blah blahBlah blah blah blah blah blahBlah blah blah blah blah blahBlah blah blah blah blah blahBlah blah blah blah blah blahBlah blah blah blah blah blahBlah blah blah blah blah blahBlah blah blah blah blah blahBlah blah blah blah blah blahBlah blah blah blah blah blahBlah blah blah blah blah blahBlah blah blah blah blah blahBlah blah blah blah blah blahBlah blah blah blah blah blahBlah blah blah blah blah blahBlah blah blah blah blah blahBlah blah blah blah blah blahBlah blah blah blah blah blahah</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <label>Blah blah blah blah blah blah</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <label>Blah blah blah blah blah blah</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <label>Blah blah blah blah blah blah</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <label>9:00am</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <label>Blah blah blah blah blah blahBlah blah blah blah blah blahBlah blah blah blah blah blahBlah blah blah blah blah blahBlah blah blah blah blah blahBlah blah blah blah blah blahBlah blah blah blah blah blahBlah blah blah blah blah blah</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <label>Blah blah blah blah blah blah</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <label>BBlah blah blah blah blah blahBlah blah blah blah blah blahBlah blah blah blah blah blahBlah blah blah blah blah blahBlah blah blah blah blah blahBlah blah blah blah blah blahBlah blah blah blah blah blahBlah blah blah blah blah blahBlah blah blah blah blah blahBlah blah blah blah blah blahBlah blah blah blah blah blahBlah blah blah blah blah blahBlah blah blah blah blah blahBlah blah blah blah blah blahBlah blah blah blah blah blahBlah blah blah blah blah blahBlah blah blah blah blah blahBlah blah blah blah blah blahBlah blah blah blah blah blahBlah blah blah blah blah blahBlah blah blah blah blah blahBlah blah blah blah blah blahBlah blah blah blah blah blahBlah blah blah blah blah blahah</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <label>Blah blah blah blah blah blah</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <label>Blah blah blah blah blah blah</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <label>Blah blah blah blah blah blah</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you provide a fiddle? That generally helps to review

Answer (score -1):

You need the overflow-x on the span3's not the span12 i think

Comment: I want to fit more content into span12 then it can fit, therefore the overflow needs to be there.

Comment: sorry, i meant overflow-y on the span3's

Comment: why would they need overflow-y?

Comment: i don't know what im talking about, sorry