# Twitter bootstrap - list of widgets / panels that can scroll horizontally

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, panel, widget, horizontal-scrolling

What would be the ideal way to implement:

1. A list of widgets / panels . I am looking for widgets like in
   iGoogle or [heft.me](http://heft.me/). A possible solution would be to use the css
   from the heft.me site, but I would like to know if there is a
   twitter bootstrap way of doing it or are there any extensions
   available ?
2. Once I achieve rendering widgets, I will be adding widgets
   dynamically. I would like these widgets to be horizontally
   scrollable. One possible solution is that I should tweak the
   carousel plugin that comes with twitter-bootstrap, but again I would
   like to know if there is a better way ?
3. Will it be advisable to maintain a list of horizontal scrolling
   widgets for smaller devices like mobile phones or is better to
   render them differently on mobile devices, may be accordion panels
   or something of that sort ?

   BTW I am using twitter-bootstrap 2.0.4

Comment: For 2 & 3 you might get information here http://stackoverflow.com/a/11333699/1478467

Comment: @Sherbrow thanks will look into them

Comment: @Sherbrow i looked into the link. I need the horizontal scroll to respond to user swipe gestures rather than controlling the scroll bar, also I wouldn't want the scroll bar to be visible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11333699/1478467) and this [jQuery plugin](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/Dragscrollable)

Here is a working solution : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/kP6v8/1/).

```html
<div class="myClass">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span5"></div>
        <div class="span5"></div>
        <div class="span5"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
div.myClass {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
div.myClass [class*="span"] {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}
```

```js
$('.myClass').dragscrollable();
```

I don't know the plugin fiability, but you should be able to retro-engineer it if you want your own version of it.

Comment: @Shebrow thanks for this piece of code, but when I try it out I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dragscrollable' " in my chrome error console. Instead I tried the jQueryUI draggable, you can check it out at http://jsfiddle.net/celestialcitizen/MACak/4/, but the problem here is that this does not exactly behave like a scroll

Comment: @Shebrow got your script working basically I did not get the the dragscrollable.js properly, I got it from your jsfiddle link,.. thanks it works now !!

Comment: @Shebrow -- dragscrollable doesn't seem to respond to user swipe gestures on android mobile phones !!

Comment: @Anand That's understandable, because "swipe gestures" must correspond to scroll on phones. Try `overflow-x: auto;` and even deactivate the plugin. Otherwise I don't know.

Comment: @Shebrow Is there anyway we could use jquery ui draggable plugin to achieve the same effect ? If yes then I can also experiment with http://touchpunch.furf.com/ plugin that translates swipe gestures to mouse actions and hopefully I can achieve something suitable for desktop and mobile browsers

Comment: @Anand It still doesn't seem to work : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/kP6v8/4/). You'll have to make buttons to scroll, or just make another question (**first, search** about touch devices scrolling)

Comment: @Shebrow I have opened a new question with more details with specific questions for touch-enabled devices at http://stackoverflow.com/q/11866345/226906