# Mobile / Touch Enabled Screens - horizontal scroll on swipe

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, touch, horizontal-scrolling, swipe-gesture

This question has been asked after a detailed discussion on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11649405/226906)

Problem:

I need a horizontal scroll which can be scrolled using mouse drag on desktops and swipe events on touch enabled screens

Possible Solution:

I tried using the jQuery dragscrollable which works fine on desktops but not on touch enabled devices

So then I went on to explore [Touch Swipe Jquery Plugin](https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin) and came up with a possible solution at [JSFiddle Code](http://jsfiddle.net/celestialcitizen/BR4Av/) and the result for the JSFiddle can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/celestialcitizen/BR4Av/embedded/result/)

You can also find a working demo at [here](http://touchswipedemo.celestialcitizen.jit.su/)

My java script code is as follows

```
//to detect if device has touch enabled
var is_touch_device = 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement;

        $(function() 
        {
                $('.myClass').dragscrollable();
                //if touch is enabled then we have to map the swipe event                         
                if(is_touch_device)
                    $('.panel_list').swipe( { swipeStatus:scroll_panel_list, allowPageScroll:'horizontal' } );
                function scroll_panel_list(event, phase, direction, distance)
                {
                    var pos = $('.myClass').scrollLeft();
                    if(direction == 'left')
                    {
                        $('.myClass').animate({scrollLeft: pos + 200} );
                    }
                    if(direction == 'right')
                    {
                        $('.myClass').animate({scrollLeft: pos - 200} );
                    }
                }    
            });​
```

I have tested it works fine on Android browser but not very reponsive on iPhone.

Can someone help me come up with a better solution ? I am using twitter bootstrap

EDIT:1

Well now I guess I might have hit upon a nice plugin in that seems to work fine on desktops and touch enabled devices, the plugin is called [jquery.dragscroll](https://github.com/iwyg/jquery.dragscroll), I have an updated demo [here](http://touchswipedemo.celestialcitizen.jit.su/)

EDIT:2

There seems to be another plugin that has support for touch-enabled devices, it is called [Overscroll](https://github.com/azoff/Overscroll). I haven't evaluated it as yet

Comment: Not working on Windows Phone 7 either

Comment: @Sherbrow for now I will be more than happy if it primarily works on iOS Devices and Android devices !! Check out my updated solution and lemme know what you think !!

Comment: The accepted answer for this question points to a dead link.

Answer (score 2):

Additionally, there is the "Swipeview" script
http://cubiq.org/swipeview

Answer (score 2):

I found an older solution and modified it for horizontal scrolling.  I've tested it on Android Chrome and iOS Safari and the listener touch events have been around a long time, so it has good support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=touch.

**Usage:**

```
touchHorizScroll('divIDtoScroll');
```

**Functions:**

```
function touchHorizScroll(id){
    if(isTouchDevice()){ //if touch events exist...
        var el=document.getElementById(id);
        var scrollStartPos=0;

        document.getElementById(id).addEventListener("touchstart", function(event) {
            scrollStartPos=this.scrollLeft+event.touches[0].pageX;              
        },false);

        document.getElementById(id).addEventListener("touchmove", function(event) {
            this.scrollLeft=scrollStartPos-event.touches[0].pageX;              
        },false);
    }
}
function isTouchDevice(){
    try{
        document.createEvent("TouchEvent");
        return true;
    }catch(e){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Original Vertical one-finger touch scroll:

http://chris-barr.com/2010/05/scrolling_a_overflowauto_element_on_a_touch_screen_device/

Vertical now has a simplified CSS solution, doesn't work for horizontal DIV scroll on mobile though:

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch
```

The question also asks for **mouse-grab on desktop**, which can be accomplished with Nice Scroll, and does work in tandem with my solution above if you need it:

https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll

```
var nice = $("#mydiv").getNiceScroll({horizrailenabled: true, hwacceleration: true});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with

http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/touchSwipe/demos/Page_scrolling.html

```
$('body').swipe({
        swipe: function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
            switch (direction) {
                case 'left':
                    // Code here
                    break;
                case 'right':
                   //Code here
                   break;
            }
        },
        allowPageScroll: "vertical"
    });
```