# Bootstrap 3 Horizontal scrollable row Website Design

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, horizontal-scrolling

I am trying to make a horizontal scroll web page using bootstrap 3. [This](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ravimallya/7kCTD/2/show/) is what I have tried so far.

```
@media (min-width:768px) {
.container {
width:100%;
}
#main-content{
     min-height: 100%;
    height: auto; 

}
#main-content > .row {
 overflow-x:scroll;
     overflow-y:hidden;
}    
#main-content > .row [class*="col-lg"], #main-content > .row [class*="col-md"], #main-content > .row [class*="col-sm"] {
    float:left;
}
```

I tried with the jquery method which mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19800008/create-horizontally-scrolling-list-item-view-using-bootstrap-columns) thread but it is not scrolling even after the width has been set to `row` class, the `col-lg` classes as displayed [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ravimallya/7kCTD/3/show/).

I also tried to set height to `row` class by getting the height of `col-lg-` height, but still not [succeeded](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ravimallya/7kCTD/4/show/).

What I wanted to achieve is:

> 1. col-lg-, col-md- and col-sm- classes should need to be scrolled with it's respective width content. the number of cols may vary according to the data.
> 2. In col-xs, there is no change in the default behavior.

http://jsfiddle.net/ravimallya/7kCTD/3/ this is the work place. Can anyone suggest a workaround? css, jquery

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Finally, I was able to get what I wanted through a CSS-only method.

```
@media (min-width:768px) {
  .container{
    width:100%;
  }
  #main-content{
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
  #main-content > .row {
    overflow-x:scroll;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
  }
  #main-content > .row [class*="col-lg"], #main-content > .row [class*="col-md"], #main-content > .row [class*="col-sm"] {
    float:none;
    display:inline-block;
    white-space:normal;
    vertical-align:top;
  }
}
```

Added `float:none` and `display:inline-block` to `col-` classes to get it to work.

You can see the working example [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ravimallya/7kCTD/9/show/). I added `niceScroll()` to get the perfect look. Edit is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ravimallya/7kCTD/9/).

Comment: Add ***vertical-align:top;*** into *** #main-content > .row [class*="col-lg"], #main-content > .row [class*="col-md"], #main-content > .row [class*="col-sm"] { *** to be perfect ;)

Comment: I published a CSS file which adds a `.row-horizon` class to allow for horizontal scrolling and also overrides bootstrap's .col-*-* classes to make the baseline width 90% instead of 100% which allows a small portion of the last column to be displayed. https://github.com/FluidApps/bootstrap-horizon

Comment: @Pier-LucGendreau that's great! however, it would be better, if you could please add a link to this SO question in your github project.

Comment: Yes! I do. check my SO profile. Though it's not an active project repo... Just for R-n-D.

Comment: @Ravimallya nicescroll does not works for horizontal scroll in mobile.

Comment: @Steeve I've not checked the nice scroll's functionality in mobile device. Moreover, the nicescroll is no longer required for mobile. You can use media queries to apply the nice scroll according to device width.