# HTML: horizontal scrolling without a scollbar

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to do horizontal scrolling without a horizontal scrollbar. In Chrome its not very hard, because you can hide the scrollbar using "overflow-y: hidden". Checkout [this](http://jsfiddle.net/9QYJ2/3/) jsfiddle.

Html:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="myWorkContent">
        <a href="assets/work/1.jpg"><img src="assets/work/1.jpg" height="190" /></a>
        <a href="assets/work/2.jpg"><img src="assets/work/2.jpg" height="190" /></a>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#main {
    height: 210px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#myWorkContent{
    width:530px;
    height:210px;
    border: 13px solid #bed5cd;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#myWorkContent a {
    display: inline;
}
```

So far a nice horizontal scroller without a scrollbar. However, in IE9/IE10 this doesn't work. Is there maybe an other solution for this problem or something missing in my css ?

Comment: What do you mean no scrollbar? There's a horizontal scroll bar there in all browsers (Chrome, IE9/10, Firefox...)

Comment: yes, except that it is hidden in Chrome

Comment: No, it's not hidden in Chrome on a PC.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20332830/bootstrap-3-horizontal-scrollable-row-website-design this may helpful to you. you can hide nicescroll handler through it's settings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The overflow separations in x and y are only a recent convention, prior to that there was no way to disable the scrollbars individually. You had a few options however:

1. Hide whichever scrollbar using another layer, you had to guess at dimensions per OS.
2. Clip the scrollbar out by either using an outer wrapping parent with `overflow: hidden` or `clip:rect()`. Again guessing dimensions, not ideal.

By the looks of things you don't actually require either scrollbar though, so you have a few more options:

1. <del>Use `overflow: hidden`.</del>
2. Use an `<iframe />` with `scrolling="no"`.

#### Overflow

In your case using `overflow: hidden` changes the way your elements extend across the horizontal. To get around this you need to calculate the sum of the widths of the items you wish to show in a row, and set this as the width of the wrapping parent.

It seems that hiding overflow actually prevents the scroll from happening what-so-ever, my memory must be failing in my old age. Could have sworn I used it previously, I guess I was relying on JavaScript more heavily that I'd thought.

So instead of using `overflow: hidden` you can use the first point I mention, which is using `overflow: auto` but you clip out the scroll bars. This can still require the need to calculate the dimensions of the horizontal parent:

Meaning:

```
[ [ 101px ] + [ 101px ] + [ 101px ] <-- wrapping parent would be 303px ]
```

But involves a slight modification of what I wrote before:

CSS:

```
.viewport-clip {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.viewport {
  width: 100px;
  height: 130px;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.horizontal {
  width: 303px;
  height: 130px;
}

.item {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  background: blue;
  margin-right: 1px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Markup:

```
<div class="viewport-clip">
  <div class="viewport">
    <div class="horizontal">
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `.viewport-clip` is used to hide away the unwanted scrollbars. We give `.viewport` an excessive extra height `+30px` so that the horizontal bars will be taken out no matter the OS — It would be a strange OS to have scrollbars that thick. This does mean you have to make sure you give your scrollable content exacting heights, you can't rely on any height percentages or anything.

As before you still use the `.viewport` element to restrict the viewable region, and it can still be scrolled using JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('viewport').scrollLeft = <pixel value here>
```

The user will definitely be able to use whatever human interface devices they have i.e. mousewheel, touch device; as the area is just a normal scrollable div. However you should always provide some UI to scroll just in case the user doesn't have this option.

#### Iframes

Another approach is to use an iframe, where you use `scrolling="no"` to disable the bars. This has the benefit of not needing to know the dimensions of your content, but comes at the price of having to deal with an iframe.

```
<iframe src="contents-to-be-scrolled.html" scrolling="no" />
```

#### Update

My recent modifications are to be found in this fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/kdRJ7/

Comment: I tried your suggestion on my mac and iPad. But it doesn't scroll. Did I miss something: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9QYJ2/5/). For now I'm only interested in a solution without js

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri ~ I don't have a peripheral device to hand to test IE8 with a sideways scroll.. but I've built a site before with this ability (albeit a number of years ago) so it should work. In order to get the modern browsers to work you'll need to include a `overflow-x: auto;` (after `overflow: hidden`) on the viewport as you were doing.

Answer (score 2):

By making the `#myworkcontent` div, you can lower the overflow, which will then be covered by your `#main` div.  Then, you can just use a div with clever relative positioning and the same color to cover the white of `#myworkcontent`.  You will also probably need to extend `#myworkcontent`'s size so that `#main` can fit within it, but the `overflow-y: hidden;` property will keep things from getting messed up.  Here's an updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9QYJ2/4/

I only didn't add the cover div, didn't have time to incorporate that but I'm sure you're familiar with absolute and relative positioning, if not check out W3 schools, they have great tutorials!

Comment: you did more or less what I already did. The problem is that it doesn't work in IE9!

Comment: Expanding the size of the div doesn't work in IE9?  I don't see why it shouldn't...maybe messing with the Z-index would allow the first div to totally cover it?

Comment: Sorry, I guess I misunderstood your issue.  Since I don't think IE9 doesn't fully support CSS3, you probably want to look into using a JS solution if you need IE9 compatibility.