# How to make a horizontally scrollable div with image thumbnails inside in bootstrap3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, scrollbar

I am trying make a horizontally scrollable div which has 3 sub-divisions inside. The sub-divisions have 4 image thumbnails inside them each. I am having trouble to get the this layout working.

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="canvas-scrollable">
        <ul class="list-inline clearfix">
            <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <table class="item-inner">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="item-thumb">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="images/#">
                        </td>
                        <td class="item-thumb">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="images/#">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="item-thumb">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="images/#">
                        </td>
                        <td class="item-thumb">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="images/#">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </li>
           <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <table class="item-inner">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="item-thumb">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="images/#">
                        </td>
                        <td class="item-thumb">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="images/#">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="item-thumb">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="images/#">
                        </td>
                        <td class="item-thumb">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="images/#">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </li>
            <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <table class="item-inner">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="item-thumb">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="images/#">
                        </td>
                        <td class="item-thumb">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="images/#">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="item-thumb">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="images/#">
                        </td>
                        <td class="item-thumb">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="images/#">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.canvas-scrollable{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

.canvas-scrollable .item-inner{
    height: 300px;
    margin: 10px;
    /*white-space:nowrap;*/
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 13px 8px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 13px 8px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-shadow: 0 13px 8px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.item-thumb{
  width: 50%;
  height:50%;
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.item-thumb img{
   height: 100%;
   object-fit: cover;
}
```

The images won't fit inside the container divs. the height: 100% is making images occupy the entire 300px height of the outermost div.

Please edit my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chandannadig/xbo1dsmh/) here.
Hope I was clear enough with my question

Comment: Take a look at this.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19800008/create-horizontally-scrolling-list-item-view-using-bootstrap-columns

Comment: I actually tried the same example before posting the question here. Everything works great except for the width of <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">. My outermost container "<div class="col-xs-12">" is actually nested inside another wrapper of width col-xs-8.    The problem I am facing is, the inner "li"s are ignoring these widths and occupying full page. Can you please edit my fiddle, or the fiddle shown in the other question to have the widths I have specified !! Thank you

Comment: Guess I got it http://jsfiddle.net/V5zWT/241/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look here .Were you trying to achieve something like this??

**CSS :**

```
ul.horizontal-slide {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

ul.horizontal-slide li[class*="span"] {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}

ul.horizontal-slide li[class*="span"]:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Check out the updated fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/2arvozpc/2/

Comment: Exactly the same layout, except instead of directly having the thumbnails like you have shown, I want 4 thumbnails each inside every sub element......... My updated fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/V5zWT/241/. In this fiddle, I want 4 thumbs each inside every list item..... as a 2*2 grid (2 rows 2 columns)

Comment: hey,  if you don't mind, can you use the same markup that I have posted with same classes to help me with your fiddle !! Thank you

Comment: i am not getting your question or what type of layout.Can you simply create some demo image in paint and show here.May be then i can help.

Comment: Please see my answer for the image

Answer (score 0):

@roxid : hey thanks for the solution, but the problem seems to persist.

The images are not showing up at all. I am using Bootstrap 3.3.2, so span2 doesn't exist...... I am getting something like this. The images are of size 0px X 0px !!!

1. [image: The output I got]
2. [image: The markup]
3. [image]

When I added my own images, the list-item occupies the entire width

1. [image: Output with my images]
2. [image: The markup]
3. [image]

I feel totally stuck my friend. Not able to figure out at all what I am missing

**UPDATE**

Made a lot of changes and finally got this layout which adjusts dynamically

[image]

**Pending Issue:**

white-space: now-wrap is not working in IE10. Can someone tell me if I have to write an IE specific code for that !!

Comment: See this http://jsfiddle.net/chandannadig/2arvozpc/4/. Everything is fine here, but the same code is not workin on my page.