# Horizontal scrolling not wroking

Tags: html, css, horizontal-scrolling

I'm using the jsfiddle/code from this question [Create horizontally scrolling List Item view using Bootstrap Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19800008/create-horizontally-scrolling-list-item-view-using-bootstrap-columns?noredirect=1&lq=1) but for some reason it doesn't work for me and I can't find out why.

I have a simple html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
 <head>
  <title>this is the title</title>
   <link href="projects.css" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>
 <body>
<div class="DocumentList">
    <ul class="list-inline">
        <li class="DocumentItem">
            <span>Test Data1</span>
        </li>
        <li class="DocumentItem">
            <span>Test Data1</span>
        </li>
        <li class="DocumentItem">
            <span>Test Data1</span>
        </li>
        <li class="DocumentItem">
            <span>Test Data1</span>
        </li>
        <li class="DocumentItem">
            <span>Test Data1</span>
        </li>
        <li class="DocumentItem">
            <span>Test Data1</span>
        </li>
        <li class="DocumentItem">
            <span>Test Data1</span>
        </li>
        <li class="DocumentItem">
            <span>Test Data1</span>
        </li>
        <li class="DocumentItem">
            <span>Test Data1</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

 </body>
</html>
```

plus my css file

```
.DocumentList
{
    overflow-x:scroll;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    height:200px;
    width:100%;
    padding: 0 15px;
}

.DocumentItem
{
    border:1px solid black;
    padding:0;
    height:200px;
}

.list-inline{
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

but only this shows up:

[image]

help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding display: inline-block to ***.DocumentItem*** will fix this issue issue!

```
border: 1px solid black;
padding: 0;
width: 500px;
display: inline-block;
height: 200px;
```

Note I've added ***width: 500px*** to your ***DocumentItem*** class so you can really see the difference!

I've also created a fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/tfdedn3y/

Comment: @teresawithoutah No worries! You can accept it if you like :D

Comment: gotta wait two more minutes, dw I got you.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.DocumentList
{
  overflow-x:scroll;
    overflow-y:hidden;
     height:200px;
    width:100%;
    padding: 0 15px;
}

.DocumentItem
{
    border:1px solid black;
    padding:0;
    height:200px;
    display:inline;
}

.list-inline{
  white-space:nowrap;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
 <head>
  <title>this is the title</title>
   <link href="projects.css" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>
 <body>
<div class="DocumentList">
    <ul class="list-inline">
        <li class="DocumentItem">
            <span>Test Data1</span>
        </li>
        <li class="DocumentItem">
            <span>Test Data1</span>
        </li>
        <li class="DocumentItem">
            <span>Test Data1</span>
        </li>
        <li class="DocumentItem">
            <span>Test Data1</span>
        </li>
        <li class="DocumentItem">
            <span>Test Data1</span>
        </li>
        <li class="DocumentItem">
            <span>Test Data1</span>
        </li>
        <li class="DocumentItem">
            <span>Test Data1</span>
        </li>
        <li class="DocumentItem">
            <span>Test Data1</span>
        </li>
        <li class="DocumentItem">
            <span>Test Data1</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this, if You set width 100% to .DocumentList so it can't scroll because scroll work with greater then 100% width.

```
.DocumentList {
   overflow-x: scroll;
   overflow-y: hidden;
   height: 200px;
   /*Width : 100%*/
   padding: 0 15px;
}
```

And Also you have to set .list-inline to grater then 100% width to scroll div.

```
.list-inline {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 110%; /* or width px also */
}
```